# Countrows with two filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I simply want to count rows consisting number "1" and "2" in a column, I used the following measure:

```
First time fix = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET), TICKET[num_replies]=1 && TICKET[num_replies]=2 , USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet], TICKET[Created]))
```

But it returns blank, how should I change the syntax in order to return a number?

Comment: Unfortunaly no as it consist sensitive data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use OR in place of AND
First time fix = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET), TICKET[num_replies]=1 || TICKET[num_replies]=2 , USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet], TICKET[Created]))
```

Comment: By replacing "&&" with "||" it worked. Thanks

Comment: Why is that you have to use OR instead of AND? It is a bit counterintuitive..

Comment: TICKET[num_replies] can be either 1 or 2. Its not both at a time.